# How do I know if a MotionEvent is relative or absolute?

Tags: android, touch

I am implementing `OnTouchListener` and am receiving MotionEvent objects. Some `ACTION_MOVE` events reports absolute X/Y coordinates, while some reports relative coordinates.

How can I ask a `MotionEvent` what kind of coordinates it currently represents?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You may want to use these for absolute coordinates (absolute, regarding the screen of the device):

[MotionEvent.getRawX()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getRawX%28%29)

[MotionEvent.getRawY()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getRawY%28%29)

The other methods, `getX()` and `getY()`, should return you coordinates relative to the `View` that dispatched them.

Comment: I have solved my problem by using said getRawX() and getRawY(). I do however find it to be a depressing solution as it suggest that getX() and getY() are useless, even though it feels like they should be the primate methods for the MotionEvent class. There MUST be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Excellent, you saved me a future headache.

Comment: Peylow -  motionEvent.getRawX() only returns absolute coords inside the view. It will NOT return coords outside the View. To get coords outside of the view one has to add the _absolute_ coordinates of an ACTION_DOWN event to the _relative_ coordinates of the corresponding  ACTION_MOVE or ACTION_UP MotionEvents

Answer (score 37):

This is a limitation on the Android platform.

`MotionEvent` will sometimes return absolute X and Y coordinates relative to the view, and sometimes relative coordinates to the previous motion event.

An event sent as `ACTION_DOWN` will always be absolute, all other events will vary. There is no way to ask the `MotionEvent` for the current type of coordinates.

This means that in practice `getX()` and `getY()` are useless for many use cases, and you should base your application logic on `getRawX()` and `getRawY()` that is guaranteed to return absolute coordinates, relative to the device screen.

Comment: Is this still the case? I'm finding getX an getY to work just fine for relative coordinates...

Answer (score 4):

When using the MapView, I was able to get the relative X and Y coordinates by subtracting the View.getLeft() and View.getTop() of the Window's content view (Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT) from the MotionEvent.getRawX() and MotionEvent.getRawY(), respectively.

The solution is discussed here:

http://andmobidev.blogspot.com/2010/01/getting-relative-coordinates-from.html

This should work for determining relative X and Y coordinates in the main layout view.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to not need the raw coordinates.

> getX() and getY() should return you coordinates relative to the View that dispatched them.

It's correct. But in general we want coordinates relative to container View, not dispatched view.

```
float xRelativeToParent = view.getX() + motionEvent.getX();
float yRelativeToParent = view.getY() + motionEvent.getY();
```

Then, to move the center of the touched view to a moving pointer position, do:

```
view.setX(xRelativeToParent - view.getWidth()/2f);
view.setY(yRelativeToParent - view.getHeight()/2f);
```