# Identifying image area clicked in Android?

Tags: android, dictionary, click, imageview

Is there a way to determine in an Android app which area of an ImageView (x,y coordinates, for instance) was clicked by a user? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) and this [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410885/how-do-i-know-if-a-motionevent-is-relative-or-absolute) question