# view.getHitRect(rect) not working

Tags: android

I am overriding `onInterceptTouch(MotionEvent)` for the purpose of  allowing horizontal scrolling.  What I am finding however is that I cannot detect when the user has touched the embedded v.  The x,y on the view are like 2000, 2400 while the `MotionEvent.getX(),getY()` are like 400,500

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.myView);

Rect r = new Rect();
v.getHitRect(r);
int[] loc = new int[2];
v.gtLocationOnScreen(loc);

int x = loc[0];
int y = loc[1];

// Result x,y are huge numbers 2400, etc
// event.getX() is 30, event.getY() == 500 nothing close to 2400.

if (r.contains((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY())
{
   return false;  // this is never true even when I click right on View v.
 }
```

Answer (score 19):

I know this is an old question and is mostly answered in the linked post, but I just came across this problem so I thought I'd fill in my solution.

```
private boolean isTouchInView(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    Rect hitBox = new Rect();
    view.getGlobalVisibleRect(hitBox);
    return hitBox.contains((int) event.getRawX(), (int) event.getRawY());
}
```

Comment: You have saved my life. I searched forever for your answer, thank you!

Comment: Do you have any idea why this works on certain devices and doesn't work any many other? it looks like the latter has an offset

Answer (score 3):

Try using `getRawX()` and `getRawY()`. These will give you the absolute positions you need.

See:

[How do I know if a MotionEvent is relative or absolute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410885/how-do-i-know-if-a-motionevent-is-relative-or-absolute)

You also have to adjust the location of your destination view to account for any displacement by other views like so:

```
int[] screenLocation = new int[2];
view.getLocationOnScreen(screenLocation);
hitRect.offset(screenLocation[0] - view.getLeft(), screenLocation[1] - view.getTop());

//Then check if source view is contained in target view

x=event.getRawX();
y=event.getRawY();

if (hitRect.contains(x, y)) {

//do your stuff

}
```

Comment: result (x,y) of view is (2180,2425),  MotionEvent.getRawX,Y = (149,1017)  again the r.contains fails

Comment: The problem Anup is that it does not work for any View v.  It works if the view is off the main parent view but not for nested views.

Comment: If you think you have an answer then please provide a generic public boolean isWithinView(View v, MotionEvent e) {} that works for any view in any level.  I will plug that in.

Comment: I don't really want the api level call to depend on an examination of every layer of the layout.  I need something generic. I still am looking for a more generic solution.